# Controlling a keypad with same I/O in C

Tags: c, matrix, key, logic, keypad

i have a problem that i have been at for over a day now, and i can not solve this with my skills.
So the problem is as follows. I am trying to get an output from a 4x4 keypad, which would not be a problem but input and output are on the same pins. I know that the 74hc573 should keep the information after LE goes low, but i just can not figure out how to read output from 74hc541 without giving new information to the previous chip, because then the state changes again. At the moment i can only read the keys diagonally, because input and output match in that case.

The schematic of the whole circuit can be seen here:

[image]

and the problematic part here:

[image]

I have tried many different way in C to make it work, but the best I can do is diagonally from 1 to C because of the shared I/O.
Hope you guys can give a tip and help me understand this.

and my code, it is only the part that should take care of getting the output.

```
    while(1)
{
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    P3_7=0;
    P3_6=1;
    in=((0b11110111>>i)&0b00001111);
    //in=0b11110111;
    *keypad=in;
    *led=in;
    P3_7=0;
    P3_6=0; 
    *keypad=0x00;
    P3_7=1;
    out=*keypad;
```

P3_7 would be RD and P3_6 would be WR, havent given them proper defines yet

Modified code

```
while(1)
{
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
        P3_7=0;
        P3_6=1;
        in=((0b11110111>>i)&0b00001111);
        *keypad=in;
        *led=*keypad;
        vardelay(100);
        P3_7=0;
        P3_6=0;
        *keypad=0xff;
        P3_7=1;
        out=(*keypad&0b00001111);
        if (in==0b1101&&out==0b1101)
        {
            P3_7=1;
            P3_6=1;
            lcd_senddata('5');
        }
        else if(in==0b1110&&out==0b1101)
        {
            P3_7=1;
            P3_6=1;
            lcd_senddata('2');
        }
```

When clicking '5' it prints both 5 and 2. And i am not sure why

Comment: I just want to make sure I'm reading this right before I try to debug anything. You're bringing one line at a time low for the scan with the shift and mask. Then with WR enabled you write the value to the bus (*keypad). Then you disable WR and RD and clear the bus, then enable RD and read the bus, correct?

Comment: Also, do you have a scope you can use to verify that the pins are doing what you expect them to, or are you limited to using the LED output for debugging?

Comment: Yea, that was the idea, but as i mentioned, it is one of many. That is just my latest one to try this thing.

I do have a scope, but since it works the way it works makes it very hard to measure anything. I have done some confirmations. Also the input ship is very small, making that one impossible to measure

Comment: It seems reasonable to me. What values are you seeing when you read the inputs?

Comment: The inputs? Unless a button is clicked, they are all ones, when i click a button the input goes to zero on that line, as it should. That is because the chip has an inverting output.

Comment: I added some more code, that maybe shows my intent better

Comment: Is this a software question or a hardware design question? Are you saying that what you write by calling (say) `*keypad = 0xAA;` is changed when you read by calling (say) `keyin = *keypad;`? Did you design this circuit, or were you given it?

Comment: I was given it, and i have to make everything that is on it work. The question is more software, but obviously the hardware side is critical to make it work.

Comment: I don't see any obvious problem with that code. I would be probing the hardware at this point, given the update with an example of it registering both 2 and 5. Set the pins to 1101 and while holding the 5 key actually probe each line to make sure you're seeing 1101 on the other end. Then set them to 1110 and see what you get - your code test seems to imply you'll still get 1101, which doesn't make sense given the schematic. It would be good to confirm that what you actually see on those lines is matching what you are reading in software.

Comment: You mentioned that is impossible to probe the input chip, but the pull up resistors seem like a good point to check the same signal, assuming they're more accessible. Otherwise, a simple trick is to temporarily solder some fine wire to the tiny leads, and clip the probes to that.

Comment: Yes i measured the inputs of the chip, and it works, i just do not know how to code it. I thought its as simple as playing around with the WR and RD but that just does not seem to be the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i was over thinking it, I had to simply write and read from the same address. That is all. a simple code like this, will work

```
    if  (*keypad=0b11111101)
    {   
        out=*keypad;
        if      (out==0b11111110)
            lcd_senddata('4');  
        else if (out==0b11111101)
            lcd_senddata('5');
        else if (out==0b11111011)
            lcd_senddata('6');  
        else if (out==0b11110111)
            lcd_senddata('E');
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is being able to control the LE pin. Latch Q1 on, then disable the LE. Scan A1-A4 to test buttons 1, 2, 3 and F. The state Q1-4 shouldn't change during the scan if LE is low. Then enable LE, switch to Q2, disable LE and scan the next row, and so on.

Comment: I already figured that out, i will add my code. It does not work tho.